# (DP) Memoization - How to know if it starts from the top or bottom?

Tags: dynamic-programming, memoization

It hasn't been long since I started studying algorithm coding tests, and I found it difficult to find regularity in Memoization.

Here are two problems.

1. Min Cost Climbing Stairs

```
You are given an integer array cost where cost[i] is the cost of ith step on a staircase. Once you pay the cost, you can either climb one or two steps.

You can either start from the step with index 0, or the step with index 1.

Return the minimum cost to reach the top of the floor.
```

[Min Cost Climbing Stairs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOEE9.png)

Recurrence Relation Formula:

```
minimumCost(i) = min(cost[i - 1] + minimumCost(i - 1), cost[i - 2] + minimumCost(i - 2))
```

2. House Robber

```
You are a professional robber planning to rob houses along a street. Each house has a certain amount of money stashed, the only constraint stopping you from robbing each of them is that adjacent houses have security systems connected and it will automatically contact the police if two adjacent houses were broken into on the same night.

Given an integer array nums representing the amount of money of each house, return the maximum amount of money you can rob tonight without alerting the police.
```

[House Robber](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpCJb.png)

Recurrence Relation Formula:

```
robFrom(i) = max(robFrom(i + 1), robFrom(i + 2) + nums(i))
```

So as you can see, first problem consist of the previous, and second problem consist of the next.
Because of this, when I try to make recursion function, start numbers are different.

1. Start from n

```
    int rec(int n, vector<int>& cost)
    {
        if(memo[n] == -1)
        {
            if(n <= 1)
            {
                memo[n] = 0;
            } else
            {
                memo[n] = min(rec(n-1, cost) + cost[n-1], rec(n-2, cost) + cost[n-2]);
            }
        }
        return memo[n];
    }

    int minCostClimbingStairs(vector<int>& cost) {
        const int n = cost.size();
        memo.assign(n+1,-1);
        return rec(n, cost); // Start from n
    }
```

2. Start from 0

```
    int getrob(int n, vector<int>& nums)
    {
        if(how_much[n] == -1)
        {
            if(n >= nums.size())
            {
                return 0;
            } else {
                how_much[n] = max(getrob(n + 1, nums), getrob(n + 2, nums) + nums[n]);
            }
        }
        return how_much[n];
    }

    int rob(vector<int>& nums) {
        how_much.assign(nums.size() + 2, -1);
        return getrob(0, nums); // Start from 0
    }
```

How can I easily know which one need to be started from 0 or n? Is there some regularity?

Or should I just solve a lot of problems and increase my sense?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is right, but somehow examples are not correct. Both the problems you shared can be done in both ways : 1. starting from top & 2. starting from bottom.

For example: Min Cost Climbing Stairs : solution that starts from 0.

```
    int[] dp;
    public int minCostClimbingStairs(int[] cost) {
        int n = cost.length;
        dp = new int[n];
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            dp[i] = -1;
        }
        rec(0, cost);
        return Math.min(dp[0], dp[1]);
    }

    int rec(int in, int[] cost) {
        if(in >= cost.length) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            if(dp[in] == -1) {
                dp[in] = cost[in] + Math.min(rec(in+1, cost), rec(in+2, cost));
            }
            return dp[in];
        }
    }
```

However, there are certain set of problems where this is not easy. Their structure is such that if you start in reverse, the computation could get complicated or mess up the future results:

Example: Reaching a target sum from numbers in an array using an index at max only 1 time. Reaching 10 in {3, 4, 6, 5, 2} : {4,6} is one answer but not {6, 2, 2} as you are using index (4) 2 times.

This can be done easily in top down way:

```
int m[M+10];
for(i=0; i<M+10; i++) m[i]=0;
   m[0]=1;

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    for(j=M; j>=a[i]; j--)
        m[j] |= m[j-a[i]];
```

If you try to implement in bottom up way, you will end up using a[i] multiple times. You can definitely do it bottom up way if you figure a out a way to tackle this messing up of states. Like using a queue to only store reached state in previous iterations and not use numbers reached in current iterations. Or even check if you keep a count in m[j] instead of just 1 and only use numbers where count is less than that of current iteration count. I think same thing should be valid for all DP.